# Submit for login review. Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm implementing Facebook login for my Flutter app. My backend is AWS Amplify. When trying to login with my Facebook account, I'm facing this warning message.

[image]

My understanding is that the review is only necessary if the app requires information other than profile and email address. The only information I'm requesting is `public_profile` and `email` as you can see from the screenshot below which I took from App Dashboard from Meta for Developers.

[image]

I tried downgrading `public_profile` access level to standard, but still getting the same warning. I want to request for App review if necessary, but I don't see a menu to do that from App Review section.

What do I have to do to get rid of this warning message? Is this by design? User can tap Continue button to sign in but this warning message doesn't look good from user's perspective. And I don't think I ever saw this message when using Facebook login in other apps. My app type is `Business` and App Mode is in `Development` if these matter.

Comment: I am facing this issue on iOS devices. Did you solve it?

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet. I'm planning to add a permission that requires review and submit an app review.

Comment: I have the exact same problem now. Did you solve it guys?

Comment: Has anyone managed to solve this problem yet? I have the same problem. Detail, on Android it works normally.

Even so, I sent it to Facebook to test, to see if they remove the restriction from my App. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: Im getting the same SH*T from facebook, have had so many problems with Facebook, not informing what is needed even though I submitted screen recordings. I have had it up to here with Facebook, and I strongly suggest a boycott of Facebook as a login provider.
Now I can not make a screen recording even with my Test User, I get the screen you are posting.
But now I need to make it work, so if you guys have a solution for this, I will be very happy to hear it.

Comment: As I read, you press button [Accept] or [Ok], then your app will be accepted. Seemly, Facebook said some countries contrained with data protection policy.

Answer (score 0):

check if in the facebook developer console in your application you have the App Mode: Development to Live setting

Answer (score 0):

We were having the exact same issue, even in Live mode.

Turns out we had to **remove `openid` from our requested scopes** so it's only `email` and `public_profile` when making the auth request.

Anything outside theses two scopes requires special review/approval, even if the Developer dashboard shows nothing about it. [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/permissions/review/)